# How to get image meta data with JS, once it starts downloading?

Tags: javascript, image, events

I need to get the height and the width of an image, once it starts downloading. From what i understand, the first few bytes of the image contain its meta data, therefore the browser knows how to draw the "frame" of the image correctly(meaning, appropriate dimensions).

Is there some event, that would perhaps notify me, when the image started downloading, and will allow me to "extract" the height and the width? Let's say, some counterpart of the "load" event.

I tried MutationObserver, but it didn't yield any results, and seems irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: how are you obtaining this image? you mentioned downloading? what do you mean by that - are you making an api call somewhere or what exactly are you doing to obtain the image

Comment: No, nothing special. I just have an img tag, and the browser starts downloading it once the DOM content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to attach your Javascript to events generated by the browser's processing of the image. I would have liked to have had this functionality myself. If you need to get the height and width of the image before it has finished downloading, you will have to do this yourself.

See [the Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) and [fetching with streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) for how to get started but note that this will only work in modern browsers.

I'm not sure what your use case is but if you wanted early meta data you could fetch each image, examine the meta data and then pipe the image as a blob URL onto the page.